# windows phone: Change Height of selected ListviewItem so that it can be like expandable list view

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, expandablelistview, listviewitem

```
<Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ListViewItem>

            </ListViewItem>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                       <StackPanel Height="{Binding height}" x:Name="ParentStackPanel">

                            <StackPanel Background="Black" x:Name="Data1" Grid.Row="0"   Grid.Column="2" Margin="200,0,0,0" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="2"></TextBlock>                      
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Background="Black" Margin="60,-80,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock Text="3"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="0,-80,0,0" Background="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock Text="4"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Aqua" x:Name="something">
                                <TextBlock Text="5"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                     </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Above is my Xaml code. I want to increase height of particular ListViewItem when clicked by the user and if the user again clicks that particular listViewItem then its height should restore to original height.
basically list view should behave like a expandable list view in android.

Comment: Are you familiar with Blend? If so, you should use VisualStateManager on your template (ControlTemplate is better for states) and doing a storyboard when you enter in the SelectedUnfocused state, and another storyboard when you leave this state. I think this doesn't work with WP 7.

Comment: Do you mean the selected item as written in the title or the item the user clicked as written in the text? Second would mean, you can "open" several items and close them.

Comment: yaa matt i mean the second one...when the user click on particular listviewItem then that particular Item should increase its height to view additional information about that item

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about windows phone, but in WPF you can use a style and triggers to drive this behaviour:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="New expanded height here" />
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        <Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
</StackPanel>
```

This is rough and typed by hand, so may not be completely accurate, but it should put you on the right track.

---

#### No Triggers

I've been informed that WP does not support triggers, so your best bet is probably using the visual state manager like in this question:

[ListBox Selected Item Style for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358891/listbox-selected-item-style-for-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: Triggers are not supported for WP 8 & 8.1.

Comment: @BertrandC. damnit - that's a shame.

Comment: @shashankjaiswal is precisely what we are doing, it's clearly a non-standard requirement and we cannot be expected to provide you with code you can just copy & paste - Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a code-writing service.

Comment: yaa clint i respect ur sentiments...professionally i am a Front End developer so i am not able to do this...and one of my frnd is insisting me to complete his college project